# Moment.js deprecation warning when comparing two dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I didn't see any SO thread that matches my use case. I'm trying to compare two dates to see if they match or not. If they don't, then I display an error message. The date format for both dates are in `'MM/DD/YYYY'` format, with the only exception being sometimes they might be `'MM/DD/YYYY'` and other times `'M/D/YYYY'`.

I'm able to get it to work but keep getting a deprecated error. I tried using the `moment.ISO_8601` argument but still keep getting the deprecated error.

```
if( !moment( start_date, moment.ISO_8601 ).isSame( user_start_date, 
  moment.ISO_8601 ) )
{
    console.log("Both dates must match!");
}
else {
    console.log("Dates match!");
}
```

The deprecated error is following:

> moment.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.

---

Is there a clean fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `'MM/DD/YYYY'` nor `'M/D/YYYY'` are ISO 8601 compliant format recognized by [`moment.ISO_8601`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/) See [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) docs to see what are ISO 8601 formats recognized by momentjs. You have to specify `'MM/DD/YYYY'` (or `'M/D/YYYY'`) format instead of using `moment.ISO_8601`.

You can use both `'MM/DD/YYYY'` and `'M/D/YYYY'` using [`moment(String, String[])`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/). This is required if you are using [strict parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Please note that:

> Starting in version **2.3.0,** Moment uses some simple heuristics to determine which format to use. In order:
>
> - Prefer formats resulting in [valid](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) dates over invalid ones.
> - Prefer formats that parse more of the string than less and use more of the format than less, i.e. prefer stricter parsing.
> - Prefer formats earlier in the array than later.

<del>For example, using `['MM/DD/YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY']`, ambigous inputs like `01/10/2017` will always be interpreted as 10th of January.</del>

Here an example that do not has *Deprecation warning*:

```js
var start_date = '11/25/2017';
var user_start_date = '27/12/2017';

if( !moment( start_date, ['MM/DD/YYYY', 'M/D/YYYY']  ).isSame( moment(user_start_date, ['MM/DD/YYYY', 'M/D/YYYY'] )) )
{
    console.log("Both dates must match!");
}
else{
    console.log("Dates match!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually see that issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/dbkidd/n9s082bj/

Can you reproduce it in the Fiddle?

```
var start_date = moment().format('MMM DD h:mm A');
var user_start_date = moment().format('MMM DD h:mm A');

if( !moment( start_date, moment.ISO_8601 ).isSame( user_start_date, 
  moment.ISO_8601 ) )
 {
   console.log("Both dates must match!");
 }
 else{
   console.log("Dates match!");
 }
```

Comment: you're right - the 'Deprecated' warning doesn't show up in fiddle. Not sure why, though. I know I have the latest version of moment.js since I downloaded (actually, clicked on the link in moment.js site which opens the js file, which I then copied into notepad, and saved into my folder as moment.js). I even made sure to completely close the chrome browser (to clear any caching) and then tried again, but it still shows up. I did update the fiddle w/ the date values that I get when console.log them in my application: http://jsfiddle.net/n9s082bj/2/

Comment: @Dallas `'MMM DD h:mm A'` is not an ISO 8601 recognized format and your code may throw "Deprecation Warning" in some environments.