# ISO format deprecation warning when providing moment in string format

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

```
const DATE_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD";
const endDate = "2020-05-05T00:00:00.000Z" (dynamic value from service)
const appValidDate = moment(endDate).subtract(1, "days").format(DATE_FORMAT);
const currentDate = moment().startOf("day").format(DATE_FORMAT);
const validDate = moment(currentDate).isSameOrBefore(appValidDate);
```

I have been trying to compare two dates using moment. While running the application, i am getting the below deprecation warning.

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: Invalid date, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error:
```

Found some usefult stackoverflow links: [Moment.js deprecation warning when comparing two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102999/moment-js-deprecation-warning-when-comparing-two-dates)

But still not able to remove the deprecation warning.

So as per the doc, need to be in string + format, so i have done like this:

```
const DATE_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD";
const endDate = "2020-05-05T00:00:00.000Z" (dynamic value from service)
const appValidDate = moment(endDate).subtract(1, "days").format(DATE_FORMAT);
const currentDate = moment().startOf("day").format(DATE_FORMAT);
const validDate = moment(currentDate, DATE_FORMAT).isSameOrBefore(appValidDate);
```

But the problem is we can't convert endDate to string & then subtract the days. If i am passing like that, getting Moment error.

Can anybody help me to find a proper solution for this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have `moment(currentDate)`. Look at the value you're assigning to `currentDate`. I would just remove both calls to `.format(DATE_FORMAT)` since you're not displaying those dates and they're best left as `moment` instances

Comment: @Phil Yes somewhere i am displaying appValidDate in code. Requirement is like endDate is in the above format (finnish date). Compare those values and display in YYY-MM-DD format how can i convert currentDate to endDate?

Comment: Format it when you display it, not before. When you're doing date arithmetic, work directly with the `moment` instances

Comment: @Phil Problem is how can i convert currentDate to endDate format? endDate is finnish Date.

Comment: If you supply as string that is not one of the recognised formats, moment.js falls back to the built-in parser, which is notoriously unreliable. Dates in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" will be parsed as UTC, but other methods work as local so *startOf("day")* will be the start of the local day, which may not coincide with the start of the UTC day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, do your date comparison using `moment` instances.

The value returned by `.format()` is a string and depending on the format chosen (and possibly your locale) may trigger the warning you're seeing.

Use `.format()` when you want to display a value.

```js
const DATE_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD";
const endDate = "2020-05-05T00:00:00.000Z" //(dynamic value from service)
const appValidDate = moment(endDate).subtract(1, "days");
const currentDate = moment().startOf("day");
// or for a UTC "start of day"
// const currentDate = moment.utc().startOf('day')
const validDate = currentDate.isSameOrBefore(appValidDate);

console.log('appValidDate:', appValidDate.format(DATE_FORMAT))
console.log('currentDate:', currentDate.format(DATE_FORMAT))
console.log('validDate:', validDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: If run in a place with a negative offset from UTC on 2020-05-06, this returns  `appValidDate: 2020-05-03` and `currentDate: 2020-05-06`.  I think the OP expects to see 2020-05-04 and 2020-05-06 respectively.

Comment: @RobG would need some clarification from OP on that one. They're comparing a date constructed from a UTC string to a local _"start of day"_. I'll add the UTC version in as an option